# How to Edit Kendo DateTimePicker on Kendo scheduler?

Tags: jquery

How can i edit the DateTimePicker on the schedular so it displays year instead of days of the month?

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
  views: [ "day", "month" ],
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    }
  ]
});
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.view("month");
</script>
```

Comment: I believe this could help you. https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index

Comment: yea i have tried using  start: "year", but it doesn't seem to be working on the scheduler but it works on individual DateTimePickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change `DateTimePicker` to year view (displays year instead of days) on `KendoScheduler` (i've just checked it on dojo telerik) :

```
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler._showCalendar();
    scheduler.popup.close();
    var calendar = scheduler.calendar;
    calendar.options.start = "year";
    calendar.options.depth = "year";
    calendar.options.format = "year";
    calendar.navigateUp();
```